# Does magmi can able to download remote images?

Tags: magento-1.7, image, magmi

**In this link:**

```
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor
```

**To set base image values**

```
image
small_image
thumbnail
```

**To set base image labels**

```
image_label (label to use for image)
small_image_label (label to use for small_image)
thumbnail_label (label to use for thumbnail image)
```

**A) Whats the differnece between '**image values***' and '**image labels**'*

**B)  All I have a productsFeed.csv file what image columns should keep in it..?**

**C) Does Magmi can able to download remote Images from URL? sinc ein my csv i have all remote images**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question - image values are the filenames of your images.  You should have all you images in the `media/import` directory.  Labels can be used to either organise them, or depending on your theme can be used for accessibility/seo (ie alt tags).

[image]

Second question.  You would include three columns, `image`, `small_image`, and `thumbnail`.  You can have the same image in all three columns, you would do that if you only had 1 image for a product.  You can also specify whether the base image is excluded from any additional media gallery or not. Use a `-` (minus) in front of any image to exclude it from the additional images gallery in your template.

[image]

Third Question: Yes -> http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor#Remote_image_support

Comment: Thnx a lot McNab.. Could you pls tell me how to set "base image values" in csv file?

Comment: `image` is the base image value

Comment: I know you've asked a few Magmi questions Joey. Once you get the hang of it you'll find the docs (which at first seem quite difficult to follow imo) are actually really comprehensive and excellent.  As is Magmi itself, you will get used to it!

Comment: i have a feed same as like this excpet that I had remote urls in place of normal urls.. i even used plugin iamge processer, but even then my remote iamges are not getting downloaded into media/import and display images in my site..

Comment: If I was you I would pull these remote images down locally first and therefore remove all the potential problems associated with that aspect from the equation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php

Comment: Thats a good idea, assume i had 2 problems now:

A) how can i save all url images into some folder? yes, in your link so much code is there, which one suits me..? i will be glad if there is some php code that takes all image urls as input and download them to some folder.. unfortunately iam not a php programmer.. any direct code available pls?

B) After i download all images, do I need to alter the remote image urls to /somethimg.jpg  in csv file ??

sorry if asked anything wrong..

Comment: Hey, now remote images ara getting in my site...but one thing : i added a new column 'small_image' (since it doesnt exist in my feed file), i wanna assign values for it from 'thumbnail' column, how can i achieve it?

Comment: Why not just add it to the feed file?  Another column called small_image. You can modify your csv using Excel or Open Office Calc, I gave some advice on the Calc route in this thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5930/couldnt-import-magento-table-rate-price-vs-destination-csv-file/7012#7012

Comment: OK fine... May I know, Why Magmi would be slow sometimes.? I sometimes feel it would be damn fast, sometimes, it adds 2 products in each second.. Any idea on this? I have 1000's of products, i thought magmi works very fast but unfortunately magmi goes slow sometimes.. Any solution on this would be appreciated

Comment: when I unchecked "Image Attributes Processor" and clicked 'import' button, products added instantly but without images..

when I check 'image atributes processor', magmi taking lot time.. its ading like 2 products per second.. so, how can i make 'image attributes processor' work fast?

Comment: You are adding your images remotely I would assume Magmi is waiting for each image to be downloaded first before it can be processed.  That's a guess though.

Comment: what If I download all images using some script, keep them in 'media/import' folder and run? then do you think magmi would run fast?

Comment: Yes, that is why I suggested it in comment 5 of this thread.

Comment: I did what you suggested me, and Magmi really run fast now! BUT there is another disadvantage behind, ie., I have some 1000's of remote images, made me to download all those images using some external software that would take some time, again reuploading them into 'media/import' folder , then only i can run Magmi, Downlaoading and reuploading images seems like hell process.. So, do you have any suggestions..?

Comment: @McNab : The link finally you mentioned above its return 404 error.